# Trying to recognize _NSFaultingMutableSet as member of NSSet

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, introspection, core-data

I'm trying to recognize the result of a generic query to a managed object as an NSSet.  Currently the class returned is a member of _NSFaultingMutableSet, which is clearly related, but fails the isMemberOf:[NSSet class] and isKindOf:[NSSet class] calls.

Given that Cocoa doesn't do a direct implementation of NSSet, it's not surprising that I've got some air in the pipes, but I'm wondering if I'm messing something obvious up or this requires a higher grade of kung-fu than I possess.

Code follows:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(someString);
 if(![self respondsToSelector:selector]){
  NSLog(@"Error processing item");
                return;
 }
 id items = [self performSelector:selector];
 Class itemsClass = [items class];
 if ( [itemsClass isKindOfClass:[NSSet class]]) {
      // do something
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ha!  My problem was solved, as usual, by RTFM.  It turns out that if you are NOT supposed to call isKindOf: on a class itself, as I was, but rather on the particular instance.  Tsk tsk.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, NSObject does have an [`isSubclassOfClass:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/isSubclassOfClass:) class method (introduced in Mac OS X 10.2). You *could* do:

```
if ([itemsClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSSet class]])
{
    // do something
}
```

Although, it probably is easier to simply test the instance itself.